# Github referring sites traffic number varies

Tags: git, github, version-control

From the traffic page, does anyone know why the number of visitors from "Referring sites" changes upon refresh?

Mainly I'm wondering what time period it reflects. It also does not seem there is a way to change this period?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because that's not really a coding problem. It's a question about a proprietary website. I think it might be better to open an issue on GitHub directly?